# ARKit: Detect whether the camera touched an ar object or not?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I have been working on AR app which is kinda portal (not using Unity) where I want to detect if the camera origin is touching a wall (box) or any AR objects. I will alert the user with haptic feedback when he collides with them.

Comment: A camera touch? Or when the camera points at the object? In Unity3D's context, there is a [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) which you can use to detect when a specified point is striking a GameObject. Also, if you're not using Unity3D, maybe avoid using the tag.

Comment: yup!, camera touch. n I removed unity3d tag!. thanks!

Comment: Hey @Santosh, you might want to clarify what is a **camera touch**

Comment: for example in this portal app, when I pass through the wall, the camera should recognize that. I wonder if this function is possible with ARKit?

Comment: @Santosh what framework are you using to render your scene? You should check out the capabilities of that framework to see if you can add a collision box around the camera and receive callbacks when it does collide with another object in your scene.

Comment: @ACVM I'm using ARKit.. I saw few coders are using box collider in unity3d ... I wonder if this is possible in ARKit. I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Santosh No problem, you can check out this blog: https://blog.markdaws.net/arkit-by-example-part-3-adding-geometry-and-physics-fun-8dd2b90037f2

You'll probably end up adding geometry and physics collision boxes in order to get the notification.